# Integrating Angularjs directives and 3rd party widgets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to build a directive that would encapsulate a 3rd party library.  My directive might look like the following:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive("shareButton", [function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs ) {
            stWidget.addEntry({
                "service": attrs.service,
                "element": elem[0],
                "url": attrs.shareUrl,
                "title": attrs.shareTitle,
                "type": attrs.type || "chicklet",
                "text": attrs.displayText || "",
                "image": attrs.shareImage
            });

        }
    };
}
```

And the use might look like this:

```
<a href="#" share-button 
            type="chicklet" 
            service="facebook" 
            share-url="{{shareUrl}}" 
            share-title="{{shareTitle}}" 
            share-image="{{shareImage}}"></a>
```

Problem comes in is when you use `{{ someValue }}` binding.  During the invocation of link method on the directive those values are passed as null.  To get those values you have to use `attrs.$observe()`.  Problem is the 3rd party library I'm using has absolutely zero ways to modify those values after calling `stWidth.addEntry()`.  I've done a ton of analyzing their code, and they use closures and local variables to make sure I can't change those values.

So I can't do anything about the 3rd party library, other than rewrite it, so my question is what can I do with Angular to either delay calling that `stWidget.addEntry()` method until I have all of the values.  Or is there a form of binding that doesn't have to use the `attrs.$observe()` method?

I don't care about binding the changes.  Simple one time binding would be enough in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$timeout` should resolve issue

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive("shareButton", [function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs ) {
           $timeout(function(){
            stWidget.addEntry({....
           },0);
});
```

Comment: Although this technically works it feels hacky because I'm working around AngularJS.  But this has less side effects in the code than the other suggestion.

Comment: will find this is a common solution. Just giving browser a chance to catch up with the compile process

Answer (score 1):

You can use scope's [$eval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval) method to evaluate the attributes against the `$scope` inside your link function:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" share-button type="chicklet" service="facebook" share-url="shareUrl"
 share-title="shareTitle" share-image="shareImage">
```

Directive link function:

```
link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
   console.log($scope.$eval(attrs.shareUrl), 
               $scope.$eval(attrs.shareTitle),
               $scope.$eval(attrs.shareImage))
   stWidget.addEntry({
      "service":  attrs.service,
       "element": elem[0],
       "url":     $scope.$eval(attrs.shareUrl),
       ...
```

Comment: I wanted to use this, but unfortunately you have to make a distinction between when one of the attrs has an expression that needs to be eval'ed vs. when the value of the field it hard coded.  I have cases where the values are hard coded and variable bound.  So figuring that out is tricky so I didn't end up using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use attrs.$observe in the link function.

See the angular directives documentation on this at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes